# Copyfromlocal hdinsight from blob

Tags: azure, hadoop, blob, azure-hdinsight

I am just getting started with HDInsight. I have some files stored in Azure storage that I want to copy into HDFS. I am trying to use fs -copyFromLocal. When I copy from the C Drive it works OK when I try to copy from blob storage using a wasb path to the blob container I get a wrong FS error. I suspect copy from Local is the wrong tool. How do I copy from a container to HDFS.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not a good idea to copy files from Azure Storage to HDFS in HDInsight. The reason for this is that anything in HDFS on an HDInsight cluster is stored on the transient instances that make up that cluster, and is essentially temporary storage.

What you probably want to do is add the storage account containing the files to the HDInsight cluster, which will make the files accessible to Hadoop as part of the wasb:// space.

You can add the storage account with the files you want access to at cluster creation, or with the process described in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cindygross/archive/2013/04/25/access-azure-blob-stores-from-hdinsight.aspx. You can also use

```
azure hdinsight cluster config storage add
```

or the PowerShell equivalent:

```
Add-AzureHDInsightStorage
```

The copyFromLocal command will only work if you have the files on the machine running the command, so you could of course download the Azure files to that local disk, but then, why move the data, when you can just link the compute cluster to it with the above?

Answer (score 0):

Try below commands.

#### cp

```
Usage: hadoop fs -cp URI [URI …] <dest>
```

Copy files from source to destination. This command allows multiple sources as well in which case the destination must be a directory.

```
Example:
hadoop fs -cp /user/hadoop/file1 /user/hadoop/file2
hadoop fs -cp /user/hadoop/file1 /user/hadoop/file2 /user/hadoop/dir
```

Exit Code: Returns 0 on success and -1 on error.

#### put

```
Usage: hadoop fs -put <localsrc> ... <dst>
```

Copy single src, or multiple srcs from local file system to the destination filesystem. Also reads input from stdin and writes to destination filesystem.

```
hadoop fs -put localfile /user/hadoop/hadoopfile
hadoop fs -put localfile1 localfile2 /user/hadoop/hadoopdir
hadoop fs -put localfile hdfs://nn.example.com/hadoop/hadoopfile
hadoop fs -put - hdfs://nn.example.com/hadoop/hadoopfile
```

Reads the input from stdin.
Exit Code: Returns 0 on success and -1 on error.

For more details and references:
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.1/hdfs_shell.html